# how to fix Index corruption in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search, index-reset

The following conditions are currently affecting index propagation to this server for search service

Search Service Application:

1. Query 1, catalog Main: index corruption detected . index corruption
2. Query 1, catalog Anchor: index corruption detected . index corruption
3. Query 1 is not being automatically disabled because the minimum number of ready query components per partition is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice here is to Reset the Index. This clears out the index and then (unfortunately) you have to perform a full crawl.